# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pdftotext, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python-3.x, pip, homebrew, ocr

I'm trying to install pdftotext (pip3 install pdftotext) and keep getting this error

```
Failed to build pdftotext
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pdftotext, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have already tried

```
 % brew install pkg-config poppler python
```

Full error:

```
~ % pip3 install pdftotext
Collecting pdftotext
  Using cached pdftotext-2.2.2.tar.gz (113 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pdftotext
  Building wheel for pdftotext (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'pdftotext' extension
      creating build
      creating build/temp.macosx-12-x86_64-cpython-311
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DPOPPLER_CPP_AT_LEAST_0_30_0=1 -DPOPPLER_CPP_AT_LEAST_0_58_0=1 -DPOPPLER_CPP_AT_LEAST_0_88_0=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/poppler/23.09.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c pdftotext.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-12-x86_64-cpython-311/pdftotext.o -Wall -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -std=c++11
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pdftotext
  Running setup.py clean for pdftotext
Failed to build pdftotext
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pdftotext, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

How do I get this package installed on MacOS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+xcrun%3A+error%3A+invalid+active+developer+path+missing+xcrun